# How do I find the resistance of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I know how the find the resistance of short circuits but this one had an extra 2 and 6 ohm resistors. So I am confused

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are already numerous resources to solve this problem on this and other sites and the user posted a homework question with no attempt to solve.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you can use a short-cut. Look at the following re-drawn circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPA1ZN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's the same circuit, but now includes resistor names. Ignore \$R_5\$ for a moment. With \$R_5\$ removed and setting \$B=0\$, you can then see that \$V_X=\frac{2}{3}V_A\$ and \$V_Y=\frac{2}{3}V_A\$, too. So, without inserting \$R_5\$, the voltage at X and Y are equal. So adding \$R_5\$ won't conduct any current and can continue to be ignored.

So the result, in this special situation, is \$R_T=\left(R_1+R_3\right)\vert\vert \left(R_2+R_4\right)=3.6\:\Omega\$. \$R_5\$ doesn't matter, so it can be ignored here.

But don't expect to get this lucky all the time.

In most other cases, you won't get so lucky. In those cases, you may either want to use nodal analysis or else use the delta-wye conversion to convert either the top delta or the bottom delta, before finishing with series-parallel analysis to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at "Wye-Delta" topology transforms.  Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform

Take the 2, 3, and 5 Ohm resistors (a Delta) and convert them into a Wye.  The 4 and 6 Ohm resistors form a series-parallel circuit with two of the "Wye" resistors, which is in series with the input Wye resistor.  This resulting topology is easily solved.